# Is TypeScript capable of shaping an argument based on another one?

Tags: typescript

My package support multiple loaders, implementing `LoaderInterface`:

```js
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
export interface LoaderOptions { }

export interface LoaderInterface {
  load(options: LoaderOptions): Object;
}

export interface SimpleLoaderOptions extends LoaderOptions {
  option1: string;
}
export interface AdvancedLoaderOptions extends LoaderOptions {
  option2: string;
}
```

`MyModule` entry point should accept two options:

- `loader` that is an instance of `LoaderInterface` (concrete class)
- `options` object witch should "match" the corresponding loader options

My problem is I dont' know how to create a "connection" between the two options.

**I need something like: *if `loader` is this, than `options` should look like this*. Possible?**

---

Solution 1: silly, becase one can pass anything to `options` argument:

```js
class MyModule {
  static create(loader: LoaderInterface, options: any) { }
}
```

Solution 2: also silly, because allow any object with the shape of `LoaderOptions` (basically, anything):

```js
class MyModule {
  static create(loader: LoaderInterface, options: LoaderOptions) { }
}

MyModule.create(new SimpleLoader, { foo: 'bar' })
```

Solution 3: better, but one can still "mix" options. But what about a custom loader with custom options?:

```js
class MyModule {
  static create(loader: LoaderInterface, options: SimpleLoaderOptions
    | AdvancedLoaderOptions) { }
}

MyModule.create(new SimpleLoader, { option1: 'foo', option2: 'bar' })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the loader interface generic. When the loader is implemented it specifies the option it supports as the generic parameter. The `create` method will be generic and will use the same type parameter for the type parameter of the loader and the options object creating thus a link between them

```
export interface LoaderOptions { }

export interface LoaderInterface<T extends LoaderOptions> {
    load(options: T): Object;
}

export interface SimpleLoaderOptions extends LoaderOptions {
    option1: string;
}
export interface AdvancedLoaderOptions extends LoaderOptions {
    option2: string;
}

class MyModule {
    static create<T extends LoaderOptions>(loader: LoaderInterface<T>, options: T & {}) {
    }
}

class LoaderAdvanced implements LoaderInterface<AdvancedLoaderOptions> {
    load(options: AdvancedLoaderOptions): Object {
        return null as any;
    }
}

let m = MyModule.create(new LoaderAdvanced(), {
    option2: '' // required since we need AdvancedLoaderOptions
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20LoaderOptions%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20LoaderInterface<T%20extends%20LoaderOptions>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20load(options%3A%20T)%3A%20Object%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20SimpleLoaderOptions%20extends%20LoaderOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20option1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20AdvancedLoaderOptions%20extends%20LoaderOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20option2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyModule%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20create<T%20extends%20LoaderOptions>(loader%3A%20LoaderInterface<T>%2C%20options%3A%20T%20%26%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20LoaderAdvanced%20implements%20LoaderInterface<AdvancedLoaderOptions>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20load(options%3A%20AdvancedLoaderOptions)%3A%20Object%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20m%20%3D%20MyModule.create(new%20LoaderAdvanced()%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20option2%3A%20''%20%2F%2F%20required%20since%20we%20need%20AdvancedLoaderOptions%0D%0A%7D))

**Note**:we use `T&{}` for the options parameter in order to decrease the priority of this inference site, ensuring `T` is dictated by the `loader` parameter not by `options`

Comment: out of interest, is that `T & {}` to decrease priority documented somewhere

Comment: It seems to work quite well, I have two questions: I can't full understand your `T&{}` even reading your note, and it seems working even omitting that. Second question is: why we can call `MyModule.create` without passing `T`? How TypeScript can understand that?

Comment: @gremo it's documented in some github issue I can't find right now. Try passing `{}` to the `create` function in the absence of `&{} `. You will get no error as `T` will be inferred to `{} `. We don't need to specify the type parameter explicitly Typescript is able to infer it in most cases.

Comment: Amazing. Amazing language and amazing answer :)